# How to configure amdgpu dpm maximum temperature?

Tags: linux, gpu, power-management, amd-radeon, temperature

On Linux, using Mesa's amdgpu open source GPU driver, I noticed that when I run a certain game on maximum settings, my computer crashes. By monitoring GPU temperature via SSH, I noticed it quickly reaches 100 °C and beyond, crashing the display (sound and SSH session are still responsive). When I tried the kernel parameter `amdgpu.dpm=1`, it takes a lot longer to reach 100 °C on the same game with the same settings, but a few seconds after reaching three digits, display crashes.

Heat dissipation problems aside, how can I set the maximum allowed temperature by the DPM, or make it more aggressive so it never reaches crashing temperatures?

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the clock speed and voltages for the different dpm levels. Though I believe you need kernel 4.17 or newer.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=238480

Comment: Please include relevant portions of the linked answer so that it is not necessary to visit the link to know the answer. Links should be kept for reference and further research, but it should not be necessary to click the link to learn the answer. Right now this is what we would call a "link-only answer" and those are not very useful on SuperUser.

Comment: I could write a program to monitor the temperature and set the clock/voltage based on temperature, but how do I know what are the safe limits? Is it enough to change the clock and leave voltage alone?